# Google Cloud Function Environmnet Timing out on every functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Edit:  I had to rollback to : npm install firebase-functions@v1.10 --save
Because apparently v2.0.0 has some system breaking changes.  I'll probably make a separate question and answer it in the hopes that some of firebase team here on SO can give us more insight.

I don't know what happen but yesterday out of the blue every single one of my google cloud functions began taking the whole 60 seconds (the default timeout limit of GCF).  I even copied the all of the code completely into a sister projects environment and and the code ran smoothly with no timeouts so I believe its all the environment and not the code itself.

Is there anything anyone can suggest looking into or tests I could run to investigate the cause of this?  I am also open to some restart reboot.

I simplified a function down below that is timing out in the first environment but not the second.  But Again remember I really don't think it has anything to do with individual functions.

```
exports.triggerRegularly = functions.storage.bucket("xxxxxxx.appspot.com").object().onFinalize((object) => {

    console.log("Hey", object);
    console.log("Hey Again", privateKey);
    console.log("Hey Again2", os.tmpdir());
    return object;

})
```

Here is an example Log from running this function (I changed the timeout from 60s to 30s when I realized the issue for obvious reasons:

```
2:00:22.605 AM triggerRegularly Function execution took 30003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

1:59:52.990 AM triggerRegularly Hey Again2 /tmp

1:59:52.989 AM triggerRegularly Hey Again -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----   
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

1:59:52.980 AM triggerRegularly Hey { bucket: xxxxxxxx}

1:59:52.604 AM triggerRegularly  Function execution started
```

edit: Turns out v2.0.0 might be straight up broken, tons of people are encountering this issue.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/283

Comment: Can you post logs?

Comment: Sure.  One moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed in firebase-functions v2.0.1. Upgrade by running the following in your functions folder:

npm i firebase-functions@latest --save

Comment: Awesome thanks,  I saw you answering some questions on this on other forums.  Appreciate you guys working to fix it so quickly.