# Firebase cloud function always timeout in logs

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am using code from this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#9

and always I get timeout in logs for cloud function, here is a code:

```
exports.sendPatrola = functions.database.ref('/test/tmp')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {

const original = change.after.val();

var payload = {
data: {
id: String(original.id),
x: String(original.x),
y: String(original.y),
dat: String(original.dat)
}
};

 var options = {
  priority: 'high',
 contentAvailable: true, 
 timeToLive: 60 * 1
};



let tokens = []; // All Device tokens to send a notification to.
// Get the list of device tokens.
return admin.database().ref('keys').once('value').then((allTokens) => {
if (allTokens.val()) {
  // Listing all tokens.
  tokens = Object.keys(allTokens.val());

  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);
}
return {results: []};
}).then((response) => {
return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
}).then(() => {
console.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
return null;
});
 }
```

Error message is: Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

What is wrong here?

Comment: Which version of  firebase-functions are you using? Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522227/function-execution-took-60002-ms-finished-with-status-timeout

Comment: See https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18032 if you're on 2.0.0

Comment: I use 2.0, it's firebase issue. Thanks to Michael!

Comment: You can now install v2.0.1 to address the issue.

Comment: Yes, now it's resolved with 2.0.1 :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Function Environmnet Timing out on every functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524052/google-cloud-function-environmnet-timing-out-on-every-functions)

Comment: currently i use firebase version 8 and i got same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way, the function `cleanupTokens` should return a promise:

```
exports.sendPatrola = functions.database.ref('/test/tmp').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const original = change.after.val();
  var payload = {
    data: {
      id: String(original.id),
      x: String(original.x),
      y: String(original.y),
      dat: String(original.dat)
    }
  };
  var options = {
    priority: 'high',
    contentAvailable: true,
    timeToLive: 60 * 1
  };
  let tokens = [];
  return admin.database().ref('keys').once('value').then((allTokens) => {
    if (allTokens.val()) {
      tokens = Object.keys(allTokens.val());
      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);
    } else {
      const result = [];
      return result;
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    return cleanupTokens(response, tokens);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Notifications have been sent and tokens cleaned up.');
    return null;
  });
});
```