# Firebase functions work correctly but finish always with timeout status

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm here to find a solutions for my project that use Firebase Firestore and Cloud Functions.

### The problem maker

Until yesterday morning everything worked perfectly. In the afternoon I read through the console that "npm" and Node could be updated. So I did it and the problems began.

#### The problem:

As first I had the famous "*$RESOURCE_DIR*" problem, solved replacing that string with "*functions*". After that, I can compile and publish functions on Firebase **(whitout edit them)**, they work correctly but have a (big) issue:
in the console log on Firebase platform, I always read foreach functions that it's closed with status **timeout** even it finished ***correctly***.

In the console I can read the message

> Successfully sent message....

and I receive the notification on device, but after 60s I receive

> Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Well... here is where I can't understand how to fix the problem. Can anyone help me please?

**This is one of the simply functions that generate the error:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.notifyProfileApproved = functions.firestore.document('/users/{user_id}')
    .onUpdate((change , context) => {
        const approvedBefore = change.before.data().approved;
        const approvedAfter = change.after.data().approved;
        
        if(approvedBefore === false && approvedAfter === true){
            var registrationToken = change.after.data().registrationToken;
            
            var message = {
                notification: {
                    title: 'Approved profile',
                    body: 'Your profile has been approved!'
                },
                token : registrationToken
            };
            
            return admin.messaging().send(message)
            .then((response) =>{
                return console.log('Successfully sent message: ', response);
            })
            .catch((error) =>{
                return console.log('Error sending message: ', error);
            });)
        }else{
            return console.log('Profile edited but not approved');
        }
    });
```

**Here there's my system infos:**
npm: 4.2.0
node: 7.10.0
firebase: 4.0.0

## UPDATE

On 17 July 2018 I received a Firebase email that tell me that my project was been automatic updated to **Blaze plan** because there was changes on Google Cloud Platform, but I never entered a **billing method**.
Without doing apparently anythings (only restart PC, re-deploy and switch to FREE **Spark Plan**), now execution time was from 50ms to 350ms, so it's OK!

A new error appear in the console even the functions work correctly. The error is:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

The function code was the same as this above. To fix that, I must returned a value everytime I haven't a promise.. so, I changed every

```
return console.log('', response);
```

with

```
console.log('', response);
return 0;
```

Now all works perfectly!

Comment: What's your question? It sounds like you resolved everything.

Comment: yes, now all works correctly.. but I don't know how to set the Topic to [SOLVED] status..
Just now, I see this comment on StackOverflow that explain what's really happened: [Michael Bleigh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51525260/firebase-cloud-function-always-timeout-in-logs?rq=1#comment90022786_51525260)

Comment: You can just answer your own question and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: thx @DougStevenson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On 17 July 2018 I received a Firebase email that tell me that my project was been automatic updated to **Blaze plan** because there was changes on Google Cloud Platform, but I never entered a **billing method**.
Without doing apparently anythings (only restart PC, re-deploy and switch to FREE **Spark Plan**), now execution time was from 50ms to 350ms, so it's OK!

A new error appear in the console even the functions work correctly. The error is:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

The function code was the same as this above. To fix that, I must returned a value everytime I haven't a promise.. so, I changed every

```
return console.log('', response);
```

with

```
console.log('', response);
return 0;
```

### UPDATE 2

There was a bug in firebase lib, fixed yesterday morning, that probably contributed in this situation. So, if you found that problem, please, try to update firebase.

Now all works perfectly!

Comment: Hi, I've got the same problem. the cloud function runs correctly but it's finishing with timeout. The most weird thing is that the cloud function is getting triggered multiple times by itself and finally finishing with status 'timeout'. This is the error message :  `{"error":{"code":500,"status":"INTERNAL","message":"function crashed","errors":["socket hang up"]}}`